# AttributeError: when solving a system of equations using classes in python

Tags: python-3.x, class, system, ode, numpy-ndarray

I have a model of two coupled ODEs [dXdt, dVdt] with some parameters (rho, F1, ...) that i want to solve using odeint from Scipy inside a class. When i tried i got an AttributeError as you can see here:

```
  File "C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Mixer_model.py", line 20, in Mixer_model
    dXdt = (1/(self.rho*Z[1]))*(self.F1*(self.x1-Z[0]) + self.F2*(self.x2-Z[0]))

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rho'
```

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
class Mixer_class:
    def __init__(self, rho, F1, F2, F, x1,x2):
        self.rho = rho
        self.F1 = F1
        self.F2 = F2
        self.F = F
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
    def Mixer_model(self, Z):
        dXdt = (1/(self.rho*Z[1]))*(self.F1*(self.x1-Z[0]) + self.F2*(self.x2-Z[0]))
        dVdt = (1/self.rho)*(self.F1 + self.F2 - self.F)
        return [dXdt, dVdt]
    t = np.arange(0,650, 22.5)
    # initial condition
    V0 = 0.75  # m^3
    x0 = 0.95
    Z0 = [x0, V0]
    # ODE solve
    Vx = odeint(Mixer_model,Z0,t)
    plt.plot(t,Vx[:,0],'ko--',linewidth = 1.5)
    plt.plot(t,Vx[:,1],'cs-',linewidth = 1.5)
    plt.ylabel('V(t) and X(t)')
    plt.xlabel('Time(sec)')
    plt.show()
Mix = Mixer_class(1000, 12.5, 6.7, 3.87, 0.42, 0.58)
```

When i run the code i got the following attributeError:

```
  File "C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Mixer_model.py", line 20, in Mixer_model
    dXdt = (1/(self.rho*Z[1]))*(self.F1*(self.x1-Z[0]) + self.F2*(self.x2-Z[0]))

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rho'
```

Could someone please help me to figure out what is going on with my code ?
Thank you all very much

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the indentation is correct in your code, that the ODE solver is not called on the class level, you have disregarded the parameter format that `odeint` expects of its ODE function. The format is

```
ode_func(y,t)
```

state vector followed by time. In your case, the passed space and time parameters go into `self` and `time`. Thus the error message.

You need to instantiate the class first, then pass a wrapped variant of the instance function to the integrator.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
class Mixer_class:
    def __init__(self, rho, F1, F2, F, x1,x2):
        self.rho = rho
        self.F1 = F1
        self.F2 = F2
        self.F = F
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
    def Mixer_model(self, Z):
        dXdt = (1/(self.rho*Z[1]))*(self.F1*(self.x1-Z[0]) + self.F2*(self.x2-Z[0]))
        dVdt = (1/self.rho)*(self.F1 + self.F2 - self.F)
        return [dXdt, dVdt]

Mix = Mixer_class(1000, 12.5, 6.7, 3.87, 0.42, 0.58)
t = np.arange(0,650, 22.5)
# initial condition
V0 = 0.75  # m^3
x0 = 0.95
Z0 = [x0, V0]
# ODE solve
Vx = odeint(lambda Z,t: Mix.Mixer_model(Z), Z0,t)
plt.plot(t,Vx[:,0],'ko--',linewidth = 1.5)
plt.plot(t,Vx[:,1],'cs-',linewidth = 1.5)
plt.ylabel('V(t) and X(t)')
plt.xlabel('Time(sec)')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternatively you could put the solver into a --properly declared-- class method. Then the wrapper looks like `lambda Z,t: self.Mixer_model(Z)`.